# DRF model serializer foreign key return object, not ID

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

when serialising a foreign key object, I'll get the object ID instead of the object. Any advise on how to get the object excluding the PK is greatly appreciated.

Output:

```
"biosamples": [
                    {
                        "short_form": "BTO_0004725",
                        "label": "embryonic fibroblast",
                        "ontology": 1
                    }
                ],
```

Models:

```
class Biosample(models.Model):
    biosample_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    ontology     = models.ForeignKey('Ontology', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='biosample_ontologies')
    short_form   = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True )
    label        = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'biosample'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label

class Ontology(models.Model):
    ontology_id     = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name            = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    short_name      = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    url             = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    base_url        = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rest_base_url   = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    prefix          = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'ontology'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers:

```
class OntologieSerializer(base.ObjectSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ontology
        fields = '__all__'

class BiosampleSerializer(base.ObjectSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Biosample
        fields = '__all__'

    ontology     = OntologieSerializer(hidden=['ontology_id'])
```

ObjectSerializer (Data is read from a spreadsheet, strings need to be empty to load):

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        # Need empty string for loading
        return {key: ('' if data[key] is None else value) for key, value in data.items()}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error, ontologie ended upin class Meta

```
class BiosampleSerializer(base.ObjectSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Biosample
        fields = '__all__'
    #Culprit:
    ontology     = OntologieSerializer(hidden=['ontology_id'])
```